# ClassFormatError while using TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader : illegal modifiers: 0x18

Tags: spring, tomcat, classloader, aspectj, load-time-weaving

I am using **TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader** to implement AspectJ Load Time Weaving.

During initial setup of my application I use **ClassUtils.getClass()** to load all classes.

At this stage I am getting

> java.lang.ClassFormatError : Method test_aroundBody0 in class com/abc/Foo has illegal modifiers: 0x18

**Foo.java** is an interface and **test()** is a default method in the interface.

I do not get this error when I use default ClassLoader.

I am using,
 
spring-instrument-tomcat-4.1.6
 
jdk-1.8.0_20
 
tomcat-7.0.47
aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar

Any suggestions or answers will be appreciated.

Comment: did you find a solution for this? getting a similar issue.